# How to get the filename from my code snippet in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
$dir = 'C:\ProgramData\AecorsoftDataIntegrator\logs\'

$StartTime = get-date

$fileList = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '2022*.log' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).fullname

$message = Get-Content $fileList | Select-String -Pattern 'TCP/IP'| Select-Object -Property -FileName ##Not getting output from this variable

if ($fileList) {
    $search = (Get-Content $fileList | Select-String -Pattern 'TCP/IP').Matches.Success
    if($search) {
        "TCP/IP error message is present in the Aecorsoft Log Files : $fileList scanned at $StartTime and $message"
    } 
    else {
        "TCP/IP error message is not present in the Aecorsoft Log Files : $fileList scanned at $StartTime and $message"
    }
} 
else {
    "No matching files found in $dir"
}
```

Comment: Remove `Get-Content $fileList` and try with `Select-String -Path $fileList -Pattern...`

Comment: Sorry not working, please note there may be more than one occurance of matching pattern. I just needed the filename if the pattern matches so that I can use the variable later. Its working in the if else loop and executing the true/false part accordingly. The output message is ok. But I want the pattern matching filename to be stored in a variable so as to use it later in another script.

Comment: I am not sure of what you are trying to do. If you keep only the last writen file (`Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`|), you don't need to select the filename because you already know it. If `Select-String` match then `$message` is not `$null` so your `$fileList` is ok, else you can clear `$fileList` for example. If you are using PowerShell 7, You can do `$message = (Get-Content $fileList | Select-String -Pattern 'TCP/IP') ?? (Clear-Variable fileList)` which clears `$fileList` only if pattern doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking for something similar to this, most of it is guessing since there is not much information in your question.

```bash
$dir   = 'C:\ProgramData\AecorsoftDataIntegrator\logs\'
$file  = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '2022*.log' |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$match = $file | Select-String -Pattern 'TCP/IP'

# if the pattern was matched in the file
if($match) {
    "TCP/IP error message is present in the Aecorsoft Log Files : {0} scanned at {1} and {2}" -f @(
        $match.Path, [datetime]::Now, $match.Line
    )
}
# if the pattern was not matched but the file exists
elseif($file) {
    "TCP/IP error message is not present in the Aecorsoft Log Files : {0} scanned at {1}" -f @(
        $file.FullName, [datetime]::Now
    )
}
# if the file does not exist
else {
    "No matching files found in $dir"
}
```

Regarding why `FileName` is not there, first of all you currently have:

```bash
Select-Object -Property -Filename
```

This will generate a new object with property `-Filename` and null value:

```bash
PS /> '' | Select-Object -Property -Filename   

-Filename
---------
```

The next issue is, even if using the right property name, the same would not be populated because [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2) only populates that property when reading a file, in this case, the cmdlet doing the reading is [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2) which should not be there.

Comment: My requirement in general is : To scan another application log ($dir) for checking that if the latest log file has TCP/IP (pattern) text in the file content ($fileList). Then check if it matches ($search) and pass that status message/ filename to Azure Log Analytics workspace. The code integration for log analytic workspace I will get in the next leg. So I was thinking how to store/pass/refer the matching filename in variable ($message) so that it can be used in the log analytic script later. Thanks for all the help.